# Connecting Telegraf to a Local Bot API Server?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot, telegraf, telegram-webhook

Can anyone please tell me how to change the server used by telegraf from "https://api.telegram.org/" to my server?

I have already the server successfully and it works properly but do not know how to connect it to telegraf.

I mean this server:
[Telegram Bot Api Local Server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kgoEw.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change an `apiRoot` option in Telegraf options:

```js
let bot = new Telegraf(process.env.TOKEN, {
  telegram: {
    apiRoot: 'http://127.0.0.1:8080'
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks you very much

Comment: you savior ♥!!!